# Error during connection to MySQL with C++ in Netbeans (Windows 7)

Tags: c++, mysql

I installed Netbeans 7.1.2 in Windows 7,

I want to connect to MySQL with C++ in Netbeans

In fact, I use the example on website

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

When running this example, I get this error:

> build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
>   /cygdrive/c/CPP/MySQLConnect/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to`_get_driver_instance'

I try to fix this error but not.

Does anyone has encountered this problem before, please give me some advices to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.